# How to create the circumference simultaneously by defining the radius in SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I want to create a circle simultaneously by drawing the radius.

The following code draws the radius.

What do I need to add to the code, so that it creates the circle (with no fill etc. just the circumference with a black stroke) simultaneously as the radius is being defined ?

```js
d3.select('body').append('svg');

function add(ink) {
  var c, p, rf = false,
    r = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    }).y(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

  ink.on('mousedown', function() {
    rf = true;
    c = d3.mouse(this);
    p = d3.select('svg').append('path').attr('d', r([c, c])).style({
      'stroke': '#000'
    });

  }).on('mouseup', function() {
    rf = false;
  }).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (rf) {
      l = r([c, d3.mouse(this).map(function(x) {
        return x - 1;
      })]);

      p.attr('d', l);
    }
  });
}

d3.select('svg').call(add);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few updates to your code for the circle with radius of the current length of the line.

- add a new variable for the circle e.g. `foo`
- draw the circle on `mousedown` with radius of 1 (so it is not visible) - you can style with no `fill` and black `stroke` etc
- in the `mousemove` handler, compute the distance between the origin and the current mouse point (less 1) and make that the radius of the circle.

```js
d3.select('body').append('svg');

function add(ink) {
  var foo; // some variable for your circle
  var c, p, rf = false,
    r = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    }).y(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

  ink.on('mousedown', function() {
    rf = true;
    c = d3.mouse(this);
    p = d3.select('svg').append('path').attr('d', r([c, c])).style({
      'stroke': '#000'
    });
    // create a circle with radius 1 on mousedown
    foo = d3.select('svg').append('circle')
      .attr('cx', c[0])
      .attr('cy', c[1])
      .attr('r', 1)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', '#000');

  }).on('mouseup', function() {
    rf = false;
  }).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (rf) {
      // pt0 is origin; pt1 is mouse location -1
      var pt0 = c;
      var pt1 = d3.mouse(this).map(function(x) {
        return x - 1;
      });

      // your new line
      l = r([pt0, pt1]);
      p.attr('d', l);
      
      // formula for distance between two points
      var dx = Math.abs(pt1[0] - pt0[0]);
      var dy = Math.abs(pt1[1] - pt0[1]);
      var d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));

      // set circle radius to distance between two points
      foo.attr('r', d);
    }
  });
}

d3.select('svg').call(add);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you @RobinMackenzie for this useful answer! I have another similar question where the goal was to put a SVG text Element above the mousepointer. I would be very grateful, if you could take a look into it: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452927)

Comment: Sure I made an answer on that other question.