# How to show the barlength in px of a SVG above the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I would like to show the barlength in px multiplied by 2, above the mouse pointer.

I tried it with `var txt = svg.append("text")` and then  `txt.text(distance);` but ended up with errors.

How do I need to edit the following code so that the barlength*2 is shown above the mouse pointer simultaneously as the barlength is increasing?

The px length * 2 should be shown above the mousepointer and stay at the place where the mouse stopped being clicked for example like this:

[image]

This far the code worked:

```js
function stretch(brush) {
  var xy0, bluebar, stay = false,
    bar = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    }).y(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

  brush.on('mousedown', function() {
    stay = true;
    xy0 = d3.mouse(this);
    bluebar = d3.select('svg').append('path').attr('d', bar([xy0, xy0])).style({
      'stroke': 'lightblue',
      'stroke-width': '50px'
    });

  }).on('mouseup', function() {
    stay = false;
  }).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (stay) {
      Bar = bar([xy0, d3.mouse(this).map(function(x) {
        return x - 1;
      })]);

      bluebar.attr('d', Bar);
    }
  });
}
d3.select('body').append('svg').call(stretch);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few updates to your code:

- add a new variable for the text element
- create the text element on `mousedown` but don't add text yet
- update the text element position on `mousemove` and calculate the label text from the distance between `xy0` and `xy1`, then make slight adjustment to the label position

To refine the label orientation with respect to the pointer and whether the pointer is dragging left/ right, up/ down; you can play with the `dx` and `dy` attributes where I have just hardcoded something reasonable for the purpose of the example.

```js
function stretch(brush) {
  var foo; // variable for text element
  var xy0, bluebar, stay = false,
    bar = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    }).y(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

  brush.on('mousedown', function() {
    stay = true;
    xy0 = d3.mouse(this);
    bluebar = d3.select('svg').append('path').attr('d', bar([xy0, xy0])).style({
      'stroke': 'lightblue',
      'stroke-width': '50px'
    });
    // append the element but no actual text
    foo = d3.select('svg')
      .append('text')
      .attr('x', xy0[0])
      .attr('y', xy0[1])
      .text(""); // start with no text

  }).on('mouseup', function() {
    stay = false;
  }).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (stay) {
      // new point
      var xy1 = d3.mouse(this).map(function(x) {
        return x - 1;
      }); 
      // your code to draw the bar
      Bar = bar([xy0, xy1]);
      bluebar.attr('d', Bar);
      
      // formula for distance between two points (for text)
      var dx = Math.abs(xy1[0] - xy0[0]);
      var dy = Math.abs(xy1[1] - xy0[1]);
      var d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));

      // move and calculate the text
      foo.attr('x', xy1[0])
        .attr('y', xy1[1])
        .text((d * 2).toFixed(0) + "px");
        
      // orient the label 
      if (xy1[0] >= xy0[0]) {
        foo.attr('dx', '0.35em');
      } else {
        foo.attr('dx', '-2.35em');
      }
      if (xy1[1] < xy0[1]) {
        foo.attr('dy', '0em');
      } else {
        foo.attr('dy', '0.75em');
      }
    }
  });
}
d3.select('body').append('svg').call(stretch);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```